# How to stop the validation trigger to start automatically in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, textbox

I have data validation in a `ViewModel`. When I load the `View`, the validation is checked without changing the content of the `TextBox`, meaning by loading the view the error styles are set to `TextBox`

Here is the code:

`XAML`

```
<TextBox {...} Text="{Binding Path=ProductName,
               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
               ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
```

On the `ViewModel`, the validations are made with data annotations:

`Code`

```
private string _productName;

[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "The Product Name can't be null or empty.")]
[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The Product Name can't be longer than 50.")]
[Uniqueness(Entities.Product, ErrorMessage = "A Product with that Name already exists ")]
public string ProductName
{
    get { return _productName; }
    set
    {
        _productName = value;
        SaveProduct.OnCanExecuteChanged();
        OnPropertyChanged("ProductName");
    }
}
```

How can I stop the validation triggering when the view loads?

I don't want the `TextBox` to show an error until data is inserted.

Comment: AttributeBased Validation has this problem and upto where I Knows nothing can be done Directly.IDataErrorInfo /INotifyDataErrorInfo are better options because we set them from the setter and this problem is not there plus we can handle everything by ourselve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validations will be checked whenever `PropertyChanged` event gets raised for property.

I suspect from constructor *you are setting property*. Instead at load, consider setting back up field of your property and not actual property.

```
_productName = "TestName";
```

Answer (score 3):

Even I had the same problem. Fixed it by using a simple trick. I defined a private boolean

```
private bool _firstLoad;
```

In the constructor I set the `_firstLoad` to true. During the data validation I return `String.Empty` if the `_firstLoad` is true. While setting your `Property` `ProductName`

```
public string ProductName
  {
    get { return _productName; }
    set
      {
        _productName = value;
        _firstLoad = false;
        SaveProduct.OnCanExecuteChanged();
        OnPropertyChanged("ProductName");
      }
 }
```

I set the `_firstLoad` to false. So now when the validation is triggered by `PropertyChanged` event the validation will work as expected.